# Howto enable instant Alt-Tabbing

Tags: 16.04, application-switcher

Currently <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> feels sluggish because it brings up a menu through which I can scroll by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times. I'd rather <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instantly moved to the next window. Same with FireFox and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a small delay before the pop up appears. So if you very briefly press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you immediately will switch.

Alternatively, you may use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for quick window switching. This immediately moves you to the next window (and back). IF you repeatedly pres <kbd>Esc</kbd> while switching, you keep moving through the windows.

Eventually, you could map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. However, you may find that the Alt+tab pop-up comes in handy when you need to move several windows over.